# How do I change the week layout?

Tags: views, theming, datetime

I need to change the calendar week view, to be more user friendly.

[image: screenshot]

The website has some dates for events, which are mainly during night; for example, there are events starting at 2AM. It doesn't make sense displaying these events in next day. If the party starts on Saturday night at 2AM, then it could be confusing for the user to display it on Sunday. How can I adapt the week templates to start the day at 5AM (instead 00:00) and finish at 24:00 (instead 24:00)?

And about multi-day dates, how to display them next to the single day dates?